# Сохранение данных из обработчика

Tags: javascript

Вот, например, есть такой простейший код, на каждую кнопку повешен обработчик событий, который просто выводит значение нажатой кнопки через console.log():

```
var calculator = function () {

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('div.button');
    var numbers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', calculate, false);
    }

    function calculate() {

        var btnValue = this.innerHTML;
        console.log(btnValue);
        return btnValue;

    }

} ();
```

Вот теперь вопрос: а как сохранить текущее значение btnValue из обработчика в переменную? Допустим если я хочу сохранить в массиве numbers значения всех кнопок которые были нажаты (btnValue), то как мне это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
var calculator = function () {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('div.button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', calculate, false);
    }

    function calculate() {
        var btnValue = this.innerHTML;
        console.log(btnValue);
        calculator.currentValue = btnValue;  // !!!
        calculator.allValues.push(btnValue); // !!!
        return btnValue;
    }

    return { 
      currentValue: null,
      allValues: [] 
    };
} ();
```